# How to deal with numeric values in Dimension?

Tags: powerbi, dax, dimensional-modeling

I have a ‘Project’ dimension and it has a discount value (in percentage). My problem is I cannot use a column from a Dimension directly in a measure…

I have to do Discount x Revenue. (Usually my dimension columns have only text values, but in this case its numeric).

Is it ok to do:

```
Measure1: = AVERAGE(Project[Discount])



Measure 2:= Measure1*Revenue
```

Or how is the correct way; one can achieve this. (My revenue is in my FactRevenue).

Comment: A numeric value in your dimension is ok if you use it to filter, sort, etc.  If you want to use it as a measure it should be in your fact table.

Comment: Please share your datasets, and model relationships. You can access columns in another table by using related or related table functions; but first you need to provide specific and clear info. It is not so difficult to achieve your goal. By the way, your 2nd measure definition is incorrect. No such thing in DAX, stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

First, the fact that the discount depends on the project may be relevant for creating the revenue records, but perhaps shouldn't matter for reporting on them.  Does it really matter *why* the discount was applied to the revenue fact?  Could the source of the discount or the rules for discounting change in the future?

So you may want to use the project's discount data during ETL to populate a column on the fact table recording the applicable discount.

Second, there's no problem using dimension data in a measure.  Something like

```
DiscountedRevenue = sumx(Revenue,Revenue[Revenue]*related(Project[Discount]))
```